# AJAX get the final page response after loading Animation is over

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, api

I am trying to fetch an html page with search results using this
https://www.gigablast.com/search?q=Paris
This page allows CORS

A loading animation is shown before the results are fetched

The ajax call is only getting the loading page but not the actual rendered page after the loading

How to skip this intermediate result?

here's my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".my_link").click(
    function() {
      console.log("requesting");
      $.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.gigablast.com/search?q=hello',
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 30000,
        error: function() {

          return true;
        },
        success: function(msg) {
          console.log(msg);

        }
      });
    });
});
```

```html
<button class="my_link">search</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the url you have specified is itself using ajax to return results. A quick look in dev tools shows that the url they use for ajax is:

`https://www.gigablast.com/search?q=hello&rand=1553268017076&uwkv=4035168804&rand=1553269522489&ziph=4035168804`

So the same as yours but with `&rand=1553268017076&uwkv=4035168804&rand=1553269522489&ziph=4035168804` additional query strings. this returns a page without the ajax loader.

Short answer is from your url you can't get the search results because they don't exist when you return the page. If you were to append the query string though you would probably get the results like you want - but I'm guessing these are a security measure that are there to prevent people from doing what you're trying to do!

Answer (score 0):

You can use beforeSend, loader after fetching, the loader will be disapper

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".my_link").click(
    function() {
      console.log("requesting");
      $.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.gigablast.com/search?q=hello',
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 30000,
        beforeSend: function() {
                $('#response').text('Loading...');
        },

        error: function() {

          return true;
        },
        success: function(msg) {
          console.log(msg);

        }
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: I think OP was referring to the target url having a loader and not his own call